# To clear Notifications in screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to clear all the notifications on the screen when I press the "clear" button. [image]

In the image as you can see, there is no new notification, but when I get the notifications on the screen and I want to clear them by clicking the clear button. I'm using React Native and JS
Please help!

Comment: use redux or Asyncstorage to store the incoming notifications and when clear is pressed clear the storage...

Comment: need more data, how are you getting the notification data? API, push notifications? sockets? and by mean clear, do you want clear from screen or delete the notification from database. to clear from screen all you have to do is empty the array and conditionally render `clear` button

Comment: these are push notifications